# lapacke conflicting with boost?

Tags: c++, boost

If I don't include `<lapacke.h>`, I get the following error:

```
test.cpp:20:23: error: ‘LAPACK_ROW_MAJOR’ was not declared in this scope
     LAPACKE_dsyev(LAPACK_ROW_MAJOR, jobz, uplo, N, &a[0], lda, &work[0]);
                   ^
test.cpp:20:76: error: ‘LAPACKE_dsyev’ was not declared in this scope
     LAPACKE_dsyev(LAPACK_ROW_MAJOR, jobz, uplo, N, &a[0], lda, &work[0]);
```

However, when I include `<lapacke.h>`, I get a long list of errors conflicting with `boost`. I believe this is tied to including `<boost/algorithm/string.hpp>` as this is the only `boost` item I am using.

Is there a known conflict with `lapacke` and `boost`? When I leave out `<boost/algorithm/string.hpp>` it compiles fine, but the more extensive code relies on that inclusion.

A minimum example for this problem is as follows:

test.h:

```
#include <lapacke.h>
#include <boost/algorithm/string.hpp>
#include <vector>
```

test.cpp:

```
#include "test.h"

void eig( std::vector< double > A, std::vector< double >& evecs, std::vector< double >&evals ) { 
    int N = (int)A.size();

    if( N == 6 ) { 
        /// A is a 3x3 symmetric tensor
        char jobz = 'V';
        char uplo = 'L';
        int N = 3;
        int lda = 3;
        int lwork = 15; 
        double work[lwork];
        double a[9] = { 
            A[0], A[3], A[4],
            A[3], A[1], A[5],
            A[4], A[5], A[2]
        };  

        LAPACKE_dsyev(LAPACK_ROW_MAJOR, jobz, uplo, N, &a[0], lda, &work[0]);

        evals[0] = work[0];
        evals[1] = work[1];
        evals[2] = work[2];

        for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
            evecs[i] = a[i];
        }   
    } else {
        fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: Unknown size of A in eig\n");
    }   
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {


    return 0;
}
```

Makefile:

```
all: test.exe

CC=g++ -std=c++11

OPTS= -O3 -Wall
LIBS= -lm -L/usr/lib/lapack -llapacke -llapack -lblas -lcblas

test.exe: $(OBJS) test.cpp
    $(CC) $(OBJS) $(DEFS) $(OPTS) test.cpp -o test.exe $(LIBS)

clean:
    rm -rf *.o
```

Comment: Can you give an example of the errors you're seeing?

Answer (score 0):

Seems this may be sensitive to include order. Try including the boost library first like so:

```
#include <boost/algorithm/string.hpp>
#include <lapacke.h>
#include <vector>
```

For me, it compiled and ran in this configuration (but did not compile if lapacke is included first).